# How to convert date time to timestampe in python?

Tags: python, datetime, time, timestamp

I have a dataset that has a column of that date written in the following format. How can I convert them to timestamp?

```
date = 1/1/2016  1:00:00 AM
```

Comment: @sleepyhead But they did not consider AM or PM

Comment: Please have another look at [ask] and try to provide a [mre], including your own attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may need to use datetime library:

```
import datetime
datestr = "1/1/2016   1:00:00 AM"

datetm =datetime.datetime.strptime(
    datestr, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')

datetime.datetime.timestamp(datetm)
```

output:

```
1451610000.0
```

More info on formats, etc.: [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)